# qtcreator offline installer: how to install without connection to web

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I need to install qt creator (actually this is not specific for qt creator , but for qt installer itself)

I've downloaded this to my RHEL7 host, which is behind a proxy (the proxy settings  configured properly but proxy allows very limited resources on wide web) and started the installer.

it hangs on "licenses pre-checking". seems the installer tries to connect to some url, can't perform this - no failure, no success, just hangs on this step.

seems like a bug - offline installer wants to be online.

any advice how to avoid this?

Comment: It looks like it is a current bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-1115

Answer (score 1):

From the QT [FAQ](https://wiki.qt.io/Ifw_FAQ) on offline installers:

> Installer does not understand if there is a network connection but not
>   a real internet access, you need to either provide internet access or
>   no network connection at all.

So it might be down to the fact that you have a minimal internet connection. Is it possible to disable the network connection on your host completely whilst running the installer?

If not, given the comment on this [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-1117?focusedCommentId=428648&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-428648) and the fact the installer uses [QNetworkProxyFactory](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkproxyfactory.html#systemProxyForQuery), you could try running the installer with the argument **--no-proxy** and/or setting the "http_proxy" environment variable to an invalid value.